# When do before() and after() get invoked within a ScalaTest class with BeforeAndAfter trait

Tags: scala, scalatest

Consider the following minimal viable self contained testcase for `BeforeAndAfter` and `BeforeAndAfterAll`:

```
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfter, BeforeAndAfterAll, FunSuite}

class BeforeAndAfterTestTest extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfter with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  override protected def beforeAll(): Unit = println("beforeAll")

  override protected def afterAll(): Unit = println("afterAll")

  override protected def before(fun: => Any)(implicit pos: Position): Unit = {
    println("before")
  }

  override protected def after(fun: => Any)(implicit pos: Position): Unit = {
    println("after")
  }

  test("hello1") { println("hello1") }

  test("hello2") { println("hello2") }
}
```

The result of running this through `scalatest` is:

[image]

So :

- The `before/afterAll` *do* execute
- The `before/after` do *not*

What is needed to have the `before` and `after` methods get invoked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are supposed to *call* `before` and `after`, not *override* them:

```
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfter, BeforeAndAfterAll, FunSuite}

class BeforeAndAfterTestTest extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfter with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  override protected def beforeAll(): Unit = println("beforeAll")

  override protected def afterAll(): Unit = println("afterAll")

  before {
    println("before")
  }

  after {
    println("after")
  }

  test("hello1") { println("hello1") }

  test("hello2") { println("hello2") }
}
```

See the documentation [here](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/#org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfter)

If you want overrideable methods, you should use `BeforeAndAfterEach`, not `BeforeAndAfter` [(doc)](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/#org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfter)